# How to install Nginx in a aws ec2 instance which is hosted on a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, devops, white-labelling

I am trying to launch the nginx on the aws ec2 instance which is launching in a private subnet. After installing everything ( i mean nginx) i am not able to access it with curl command also. I searched a lot in Google I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Since you have installed in private subnet ec2 that's why not able to access using curl.
Now have below solutions

1. Use a Public load balancer in front of ec2
2. Use session manager (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ssh-vpc-resources/)